# Итерацию по вектору объектов

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++14

QtCreator, cmake. Не даёт проитерироваться по вектору объектов и передать их в функцию.

```
Ошибка /home/bai/pplab1/main.cpp:19: ошибка: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Detail'
    for (Detail counter : listDetail) {
            ^       ~
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "machine.h"
#include "detail.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void Process(Detail &list_p) {
    while(list_p.Get_machine_list().size() > 0 && list_p.Get_state() < 3) {
        if (list_p.Get_last_time() > 0) {
            int temp = list_p.Get_last_time();
            list_p.Set_last_time(--temp);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    }
}
void Start(const std::vector<Detail> &listDetail) {
    for (Detail counter : listDetail) {
        Process(counter);
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<Machine>listMachine = {{1, "Collector"}, {2,"Painter"}, {3, "Polisher"}};
    std::vector<Detail>listDetail = {{1, "LadaPriora", 3, listMachine[0], listMachine[1]}, {2, "KiaRio", 4, listMachine[2]},
                                     {3, "FordFocus", 7, listMachine[1], listMachine[2]}, {4, "ToyotaPrado", 9, listMachine[0]}};
    std::cout << "N | ";
    for (auto &x : listMachine){
        std::cout << "  R" << x.Get_id() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << " | ";
    for (auto &x : listDetail) {
        std::cout << " P" << x.Get_id() << "     ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    Start(listDetail);
    return 0;
}
```

UPD:
Исправил строку:

```
void Start(std::vector<Detail> &listDetail) {
    for (Detail &counter : listDetail) {
        Process(counter);
    }
}
```

Но появилась ошибка

```
/usr/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75: ошибка: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Detail'
    { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                                     ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Ну так  а где полная информация об ошибке? Компилятор вам дал полный контекст, вплоть до конкретной строчки в *вашем* коде. Вы же нам даете какой-то огрызок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вам же прямо говорит компилятор: у вашего класса отсутствует конструктор копирования. В вашем for просто обращайтесь к по ссылке.

А ещё конструктор вектора не может принимать объекты без конструктора копирования (по крайней мере в таком виде). Если вы используете 11 стандарт, то просто создайте пустой вектор и заполните его с помощью emplace_back.

Comment: Я обращался к counter по ссылке, компилятор `/usr/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75: ошибка: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Detail'
    { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }`

Comment: А если использую 14 стандарт то описать конструктор копирования в классе ?

Comment: @Aleksey нет, я перепутал, не 17, а 11 стандарт